# How to make circle / g / path element in SVG pulse

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I have an `SVG` of the following map:

[image]

On the map, you will notice the orange dots. I'm looking to make these dots pulsate like this:

```css
.pulse {
  margin:100px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="pulse"></span>
```

**Challenges**:

1. `html` markup cannot be used within `svg`'s, so using the `span` as the demo above is not an option.
2. In order to make sure the dots are still positioned correctly, I've added parent `g` elements and moved the child `transform` property onto the parent.

Here is the original (simplified) map:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="37.013" height="41.348" viewBox="0 0 37.013 41.348">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Ellipse_160" x="0.013" y="3.485" width="37" height="37" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.271"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Group_1132" data-name="Group 1132" transform="translate(-624.987 -1061.515)">
    <g id="Group_973" data-name="Group 973" transform="translate(121.865 791.121)">
      <g id="Group_966" data-name="Group 966" transform="translate(503.497 270.783)">
        <g id="Group_964" data-name="Group 964">
          <path id="Path_110983" data-name="Path 110983" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110984" data-name="Path 110984" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110985" data-name="Path 110985" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Group_965" data-name="Group 965">
          <path id="Path_110986" data-name="Path 110986" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110987" data-name="Path 110987" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110988" data-name="Path 110988" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="Group_975" data-name="Group 975">
      <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 624.99, 1061.51)" filter="url(#Ellipse_160)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_160-2" data-name="Ellipse 160" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5" transform="translate(9.01 9.49)" fill="#ff7c81"/>
      </g>
      <circle id="Ellipse_161" data-name="Ellipse 161" cx="5.5" cy="5.5" r="5.5" transform="translate(638 1075)" fill="#ffee7e"/>
    </g>
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here is my attempt at applying the pulse effect:

```css
.map--pulse {
  margin: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}


@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="map">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="37.013" height="41.348" viewBox="0 0 37.013 41.348">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Ellipse_160" x="0.013" y="3.485" width="37" height="37" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.271"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Group_1132" data-name="Group 1132" transform="translate(-624.987 -1061.515)">
    <g id="Group_973" data-name="Group 973" transform="translate(121.865 791.121)">
      <g id="Group_966" data-name="Group 966" transform="translate(503.497 270.783)">
        <g id="Group_964" data-name="Group 964">
          <path id="Path_110983" data-name="Path 110983" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110984" data-name="Path 110984" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110985" data-name="Path 110985" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Group_965" data-name="Group 965">
          <path id="Path_110986" data-name="Path 110986" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110987" data-name="Path 110987" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110988" data-name="Path 110988" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>

  
    <!-- dot here -->
    <g class="map__group" id="Group_975" data-name="Group 975">
      <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 624.99, 1061.51)" filter="url(#Ellipse_160)">
        <g transform="translate(9.01 9.49)">
          <circle class="map--pulse" id="Ellipse_160-2" data-name="Ellipse 160" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5"  fill="#ff7c81"/>
        </g>
    </g>
      
      <circle id="Ellipse_161" data-name="Ellipse 161" cx="5.5" cy="5.5" r="5.5" transform="translate(638 1075)" fill="#ffee7e"/>
    </g>
    
  </g>
</svg>


</div>
```

As you can see, nothing happens.

I then thought maybe the effect needs to take place on a `path` rather than `circle` and tried:

`<path class="map--pulse" id="Ellipse_160-2" data-name="Ellipse 160" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5"  fill="#ff7c81"/>`

Instead of:

`<circle class="map--pulse" id="Ellipse_160-2" data-name="Ellipse 160" cx="9.5" cy="9.5" r="9.5"  fill="#ff7c81"/>`

But all this did was hide my orange `circle`.

Is a pulse effect possible here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so?  Using CSS Animation for Map Markers

```css
circle {
  fill: gold;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}
svg > circle:last-child {
  fill: gold;
  opacity: 1;
}
#rp1 {
  animation: ripple1 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2.5);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
#rp2 {
  animation: ripple2 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
#rp3 {
  animation: ripple3 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
#rp4 {
  animation: ripple4 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="map">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="370" height="410" viewBox="0 0 37.013 41.348"> 
<defs>
  <g id="Group_975" >
    <circle id="rp1" cx="20" cy="20" r="1" />
    <circle id="rp2" cx="20" cy="20" r="1" />
    <circle id="rp3" cx="20" cy="20" r="1" />
    <circle id="rp4" cx="20" cy="20" r="1" />
  </g>
</defs>
 
  <g id="Group_1132" data-name="Group 1132" transform="translate(-624.987 -1061.515)">
    <g id="Group_973" data-name="Group 973" transform="translate(121.865 791.121)">
      <g id="Group_966" data-name="Group 966" transform="translate(503.497 270.783)">
        <g id="Group_964" data-name="Group 964">
          <path id="Path_110983" data-name="Path 110983" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110984" data-name="Path 110984" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110985" data-name="Path 110985" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Group_965" data-name="Group 965">
          <path id="Path_110986" data-name="Path 110986" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110987" data-name="Path 110987" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110988" data-name="Path 110988" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
     
  </g>
   <!-- dot here -->
     <use xlink:href="#Group_975" x="1" y="3"/>
       <circle r="1" cx="21" cy="23" /> 
</svg>
</div>
```

*Option using a map in `*.png` format*

The map image is added using the `<image>` tag

This will allow you to place markers on top of the map and link them to certain places on the map. The relative position of markers and places on the map will remain the same regardless of zooming and using any gadget.

[image]

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
circle {
  fill: gold;
  opacity: 1;
  
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#anim-circle {
  fill: crimson;
  opacity: 0.3;
  animation: ripple1 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes ripple1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 2200 1200" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cosLH.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
 <!-- dot here -->
 <defs>
 <g id="Group_975">
   <circle id="anim-circle" cx="250" cy="250" r="15"></circle>
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="15"></circle>
 </g>
 </defs>   
   <use xlink:href="#Group_975"  /> 
     <use xlink:href="#Group_975" x="160" y="300" />
      <use xlink:href="#Group_975" x="750" y="200" /> 
        <use xlink:href="#Group_975" x="1435" y="650" />

</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I have two separate SVG element (but it could be just one). In the first I define a `<symbol>` with a shadow and a circle that is animated. The first SVG takes up no space (width and height are 0).

In the second SVG you find the map. I didn't change anything here except the width. By using `<use>` I can now place the pulsating circle on the map. The nice thing about `<use>` is that it has it's own viewBox. So, the sizes defined in the symbol will scale according to the size used by the `<use>` element. Like this:

```
<use href="#pulse" width="4" height="4" x="21" y="27"/>
```

This will place the dot (21,27 from the upper left corner) according to the viewBox `viewBox="0 0 37.013 41.348"`.

The two dots I already made are two different sizes -- the size can be adjusted according to the viewBox. The tricky part here is using transform/translate for placing the dot in the right spot. I'm not able to see what all you transform/translate one the `<g>`'s does. So, here a matter of experimenting.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="0" flood-color="orange">
        <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" values="0;2" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </feDropShadow>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="pulse" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
    <circle filter="url(#shadow)" cx="2" cy="2" r="1" fill="orange"/>
    <circle  cx="2" cy="2" r="1" fill="orange">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="1;2" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="map">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" viewBox="0 0 37.013 41.348">
  <g id="Group_1132" data-name="Group 1132" transform="translate(-624.987 -1061.515)">
    <g id="Group_973" data-name="Group 973" transform="translate(121.865 791.121)">
      <g id="Group_966" data-name="Group 966" transform="translate(503.497 270.783)">
        <g id="Group_964" data-name="Group 964">
          <path id="Path_110983" data-name="Path 110983" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110984" data-name="Path 110984" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110985" data-name="Path 110985" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Group_965" data-name="Group 965">
          <path id="Path_110986" data-name="Path 110986" d="M770.107,357.625c-.789.869-1.608,2.413-1.014,2.391.735-.029,1.535-.866,1.917-1.656A2.834,2.834,0,0,1,770.107,357.625Z" transform="translate(-765.982 -354.8)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110987" data-name="Path 110987" d="M795.956,382.39c-.124-.042-.247-.088-.375-.121a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.965-1.451.371.371,0,0,0-.2.191c-.312.771-.982.676-1.474-.189s.448-1.69-.043-1.785a2.02,2.02,0,0,1-.983-1.783.721.721,0,0,0,.008-.208,8.945,8.945,0,0,1-1.51-1.692,2.344,2.344,0,0,1-.376-.879l-.254-.122a3.174,3.174,0,0,1-1.514-1.893,2.492,2.492,0,0,1-.122-.866c-.083-.241-.153-.49-.213-.739a3.278,3.278,0,0,1-1.659-2.59,1.641,1.641,0,0,1-.657-.555c-.759-1.061-2.054-.53-2.725-.482-.583.042-.15-1.013.679-1.794a3.815,3.815,0,0,1-.2-1.022,3.208,3.208,0,0,1,1.979-2.909,4.018,4.018,0,0,1,.633-.756c.013-.012.029-.02.042-.032a6.426,6.426,0,0,0,.259-1.3c0-.821-4.688-.773-5.582-.29s-1.786-.722-1.028-1.061,2.368-2.023,2.277-2.7,1.117-1.3.448-1.928-.76.82-1.34,1.3-1.876.339-3.261.049a1.147,1.147,0,0,0-.471,0A3.019,3.019,0,0,1,775,356.733a3.6,3.6,0,0,0-.07.8c.046.916-1.608,1.446-1.34,2.217s-.312,1.349-.758.914-.938-1.494-1.831-.722,1.027,1.785,2.186,1.93-.891,1.06-1.115,2.407,1.517.774,1.608,1.735-2.5,1.11-2.5,2.024,1.474-.432,2.144-.817-.356,2.263,1.252,1.975,1.159-2.649,1.741-2.554-.268,1.253.225,2.264-1.162,2.556-1.073,3.28,3.3.722,4.331-.434,1.518.1.8.965a1.174,1.174,0,0,0,.493,2.025c.891.336,1.2.432.8,1.2s-.046,2.217-.269,2.94-2.992.627-3.08.146-1.252-.146-.938.529-.983,1.4-.893,2.025,1.74.481,1.785,1.254-1.206,1.685-2.9,2.217.356,1.976,1.16,1.348.625.433,1.787.433,1.876,1.012,3.169.483,1.251,0,.268.819-2.455-.048-3.349.483-4.526,4.206-3.839,5.11c.4.529.935-.771,2.231-1.35a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.393.025,3.663,3.663,0,0,1,1.222-1.2,3.486,3.486,0,0,1,2.538-.319,3.192,3.192,0,0,1,.51.188c.033,0,.062,0,.1.009a2.682,2.682,0,0,0,2.368-.724c.536-.482,1.963.961,2.412.625a8.277,8.277,0,0,1,3.393-.676,9.067,9.067,0,0,0,4.2-1.88c.67-.673-.4-.817-1.293-.673s-.716-.965.221-1.928,2.412-1.686,2.5-3.132v-.005C796.375,382.59,796.166,382.488,795.956,382.39Z" transform="translate(-766.638 -353.284)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
          <path id="Path_110988" data-name="Path 110988" d="M766.166,380.548a3.416,3.416,0,0,1-.822,1.858c-.473.366-1.35,1.748-.676,1.9s1.753,1.31,1.89.435.607-2.039,1.754-.583a6.255,6.255,0,0,0,1,.979c.186-.661,1.6-.775,2.329-1.57.894-.965-.445-2.363-1.694-3.662C768.816,378.724,767.359,380.568,766.166,380.548Z" transform="translate(-764.422 -362.441)" fill="#5f249f" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="0.75"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    </g>
  
  <!-- dot here -->
  <use href="#pulse" width="4" height="4" x="21" y="27"/>
  <use href="#pulse" width="2" height="2" x="12" y="15"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Update

To adjust the the "pulsation" you can play around with the attributes *value*, *keyTimes* and *dur* on the animation element. The value is a list of values that the attribute will have over the span of the duration (*dur*). It will have two or more values. If there are more than two values (like the animation of *r* in the below example), the *keyTimes* attribute can be used for setting the the intermediate pace. So here the value will be 0 at 0 seconds, 1 after 1.5 seconds (0.75), and 0 after 2 seconds (1).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="300">
  <symbol id="pulse" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" fill="orange"/>
    <circle  cx="2" cy="2" r="1" fill="orange">
      <animate attributeName="r" values="1;2;1" keyTimes="0; 0.75; 1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
  </symbol>
  
  <use href="#pulse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
  <use href="#pulse" x="0" y="0" width="1.5" height="1.5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very different approach, which looks interesting! One question in your `<use>` elements, how did you determine the `transform` `value`? For example, in your first `<use>`, you have `transform="translate(18 5)"`, in my original demo, I don't have anything with `transform="translate(18 5)"`?

Comment: @Freddy I updated my answer. This thing about the transform/translate was not clear. I resized the symbol a bit and then use the x and y attributes on the `<use>` instead. This makes it more clear how the dots are placed (I hope...).

Comment: Ah, I see, managed to implement `use` in my bigger map :) Another question, in your demo, the dots pulsate and then reset (they hide for a microsecond, then reappear), is that a way to make it more fluid, so that it doesn't hide?

Comment: @Freddy I made a second example just with the symbol and a small explanation. There could probably be different approaches to a more smooth animation. Try yourself.